# How to organize MVC3 project in custom folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I’m starting to learn MVC3 and I’d like to know if it is advisable to group your views and controllers in folders different to the default ones.
So I could organize the project such as:

-->ClientsFolder
-Views
----ClientsAdmin(Folder)
------View1
------View2
------View3
----ClientInvoices(Folder)
------View1
------View2
------View3
-Controllers
----ClientsAdminController(File)
----ClientsInvoiceController(File)
-->EmployeesFolder
 Etc..
 Etc..
I’d like to know, if it is a common practise, how should I start to adapt the project to this structure or if somebody could point me to a tutorial which could help me started.

Thanks

Comment: @Valamas - that's an odd comment, can you expand?

Comment: If you move where the view are, controllers won't be able to find them by default. You could tinker with the viewengine (ie make your own) to change where it looks. You can also specify the longer path within your controllers when you return a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a feature MVC 3 already has (since MVC 2 I think). **Areas**.

[Walkthrough: Organizing an Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.98).aspx)

UPDATE: New working link.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine. There's no need for a new area for every controller, areas should be for large chunks of application that aren't really the main application (like an administration site for your main site).
This is an OK tutorial to get started [MVC Movie Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)

Comment: Thanks for the link.... maybe it's me but I can't seem to see anything related to reorganizing the default structure of an mvc3 project...

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize you wanted a link on how to lay out the project. I'm not too sure I've ever came across one like that. For a basic app, the way your going is OK though. Look up Areas and maybe there will be some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) for arrange mvc project.
Don't invent the wheel again... =)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC has a facility to partition Web applications into smaller units with [areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx).

For example you can create an admin area for the administration section.